# Waiting until a callback has finished handling a reponse

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback, notify

A thread, let's call it `Thread A` can trigger an asynchronous `HttpRequest`, which occurs by passing it a callback which handles the `HttpResponse`. In the common case, this is fine, as this happens in the background. However, I am adding a function which ideally would want to trigger polling but only return once these `HttpResponse` messages are finished being handled by the callback. This is to ensure some state is consistent before the program continues.

Is there a good way to block on this asynchronous event getting *handled*. Note that I am not waiting for the response, I am waiting for it to be handled accordingly after it gets the response.

Comment: what have you tried so far, and what problems are you facing?

Comment: I might have a possible solution, but I'd need to see an example with code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have considered using Java's inbuilt `wait()` and `notify()`, using a new object. But this seems a bit primitive.